# Need Dominion Land Survey (DLS) grids loaded into QGIS for province of Saskatchewan in Canada

Tags: grids-graticules, boundaries, canada, agriculture

I found a source that allows the download of a shapefile for the grid system for Alberta, but am still in need of the same thing for the entire Dominion Land Survey Grid, or just Saskatchewan.

I'm working in the Agriculture industry on boundaries for fields. There are resources for locating specific locations, but I need to be able to create the boundaries in QGIS.

Comment: Like SaskGrid_TOWNSHIP feature layer, as part of the ISC Sask Grid TFM data set? https://gis.saskatchewan.ca/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastre/FeatureServer/0

Comment: @Mapperz That appears to be what I'm after! Any chance someone could tell me how to get it from this source into my qgis?

Answer (score 1):

Using QGIS and the ArcGIS Feature Server connection use the url

```
https://gis.saskatchewan.ca/arcgis/rest/services/
```

[image]

to export as shapefile 'right click the layer and save as shapefile'

Comment: Thanks you're a life saver! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing this week and while the connection provided by Mapperz works, for whatever reason - the Cadastre layers shown (in Mapperz's nice screenshot) are no longer showing today.  I found an archive of Cadastre layers (Township,Section,etc) on a public drive (link below) which was appropriate for my purposes.
[image: Zip Contents List Screenshot]

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y8-CH7vZB1AHt49WziNn7ihp-GxhItpg?usp=sharing